# primitive binary quadratic forms and the number of automorphs.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

For a given integer $d<0$, is it true that all the primitive positive definite binary quadratic forms of discriminant $d$, have the same number of automorphs? If so, then how to prove it?

Thanks.